# asp.net ajax update some part after loading the rest of the webpage

Tags: asp.net, ajax

A portion of my site requires data from a web service, with takes 7-8 seconds. How can I load the rest of the website, show a Updateprogress for the data which comes from the service, than show the data once obtained trough a updatepannel.

Some working project would be great. Thanks

I need the server to retun the page before the data from service is obtained, and add that data later using ajax

Answer (score 0):

if you are using Visual Studio 2008 then You can use AJAX Extensions tab in toolbox. There you can use UpdatePanel and UpdateProgress controll

Comment: I already use those, but I need the server to retun the page before the data from service is obtained, and add that data later

Comment: for this you need to call service in javascript fuction or you can refresh updatepanel through javascript fuction. In this situation your page will displayed first.

Comment: can I get a full gridview with custom columns trough webservices?

Comment: you can get DataSet from webservice not Gridview

Comment: is there any tutorial for something like this? how do I bind the data comming from the webservice to the grid on the client side?